# How did Adam and Eve die?

Tags: adam-and-eve

I have a few related questions:

- How did Adam and Eve die?
- Who died first - Adam or Eve?
- Were Adam and Eve buried after their deaths?

Comment: wow that was a very interesting question I dont know why it never crossed my mind, or if it did I dont recall it.
Thanks for this question and for the answer Starman, this has certainly got me thinking

Comment: @Jess: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  StackExchange sites are a bit different from other discussion-type sites such as forums.  The Answer feature really is only for *answering questions.*  If you have comments on a question or an answer, please use the Comments instead.  I've converted your answer to a comment, since it fits better as one.  Thanks for your participation, though.  Please have a look at the FAQ link at the top of the page; it gives a simple overview of how the site and the community work. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adam (and presumably Eve) simply died of old age.

> [**Genesis 5:5 (NIV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%205:5&version=NIV)
>   <sup>5</sup> Altogether, Adam lived a total of 930 years, and then he died.

As for where they're buried, I don't think that's recorded anywhere in the Bible. Who died first certainly isn't recorded; that bit of trivia likely wouldn't have been important to people of the time.

Comment: I agree that who died when is trivia. The fact that *anyone was dying at all* is the biggest headline at this stage in Earth's history.

Comment: I had read somewhere that there is a tradition that Golgotha ("Skull") refers to Adam's skull and he was buried there. This may be more legend than tradition, I don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

**How did Adam and Eve die?**

We may never know how either Adam or Eve died, where they were buried or who died first.

Here is what we know from Scriptures:

> 5 This is the book of the generations of Adam. When God created man, ohe made him in the likeness of God. 2 Male and female he created them, and he blessed them and named them Man1 when they were created. 3 When Adam had lived 130 years, he fathered a son in his own likeness, after his image, and pnamed him Seth. 4 The days of Adam after he fathered Seth were 800 years; and he had other sons and daughters. 5 Thus all the days that Adam lived were 930 years, rand he died. - [Genesis 5:1-5](https://www.esv.org/Genesis+5/)

Adam and Eve had another Son after Cain had killed his brother Abel. Thus we know that Eve lived at least 130 years according to Scriptures.

> 25 And Adam knew his wife again, and she bore a son and called his name Seth, for she said, “God has appointed7 for me another offspring instead of Abel, for Cain killed him.” 26 To Seth also a son was born, and he called his name mEnosh. At that time people began nto call upon the name of the Lord. - [Genesis 4:25-26](https://www.esv.org/Genesis+4/)

It is generally believed that Adam outlived his wife Eve. One Jewish tradition tells us that both Adam and Eve were buried in the [Cave of the Patriarchs](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/588225/jewish/Cave-of-the-Patriarchs-Mearat-Hamachpelah.htm) at Machpelah (Hebron, Israel), the very field and cave that Abraham had purchased as a burial place for himself and his descendants.

> 23 And Sarah was an hundred and seven and twenty years old: these were the years of the life of Sarah.
>
> 2 And Sarah died in Kirjatharba; the same is Hebron in the land of Canaan: and Abraham came to mourn for Sarah, and to weep for her.
>
> 3 And Abraham stood up from before his dead, and spake unto the sons of Heth, saying,
>
> 4 I am a stranger and a sojourner with you: give me a possession of a buryingplace with you, that I may bury my dead out of my sight.
>
> 5 And the children of Heth answered Abraham, saying unto him,
>
> 6 Hear us, my lord: thou art a mighty prince among us: in the choice of our sepulchres bury thy dead; none of us shall withhold from thee his sepulchre, but that thou mayest bury thy dead.
>
> 7 And Abraham stood up, and bowed himself to the people of the land, even to the children of Heth.
>
> 8 And he communed with them, saying, If it be your mind that I should bury my dead out of my sight; hear me, and intreat for me to Ephron the son of Zohar,
>
> 9 That he may give me the cave of Machpelah, which he hath, which is in the end of his field; for as much money as it is worth he shall give it me for a possession of a buryingplace amongst you. - [Genesis 23:1-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2023&version=KJV)

The Jewish Encyclopedia has this to say about this tradition:

> **Biblical and Post-Biblical Data:**
>
> Name of a field and cave bought by Abraham as a burying-place. The meaning of the name, which always occurs with the definite article, is not clear; according to the Targumim and the Septuagint it means "the double," while Gesenius ("Th."), with more reason, connects it with the Ethiopic for "the portion." It appears to have been situated near Mamre, or Hebron, and to have belonged to Epbron the Hittite. Abraham needed a burying-place for Sarah, and bought the field of the Machpelah, at the end of which was a cave, paying four hundred silver shekels. The cave became the family burying-place, Sarah being the first to be buried there; later, Abraham, Isaac, Rebekah, Leah, and Jacob were placed there (Gen. xxiii. 9, 16-20; xxv. 9; xlix. 30-31; 1. 13). It is designated twice only as the "cave" of the Machpelah (Gen. xxiii. 9, xxv. 9); in the other instances it is called "the cave of the field of the Machpelah" or "the cave in the field of the Machpelah." No further reference is made to it or to the burying-place of the Patriarchs, though some scholars find an allusion to it in II Sam. xv. 7, 9.
>
> Josephus speaks of the purchase of Ephron's field at Hebron by Abraham as a place of burial and of the tombs (Μνημεῖα) built there by Abraham and his descendants, without, however, mentioning the name "Machpelah" ("Ant." i. 14. 22). In the twelfth century the cave of the Machpelah began to attract visitors and pilgrims, and this aroused the curiosity and wonder of the natives. Benjamin of Tudela relates: "At Hebron there is a large place of worship called 'St. Abraham,' which was previously a Jewish synagogue. The natives erected there six sepulchers, which they tell foreigners are those of the Patriarchs and their wives, demanding money as a condition of seeing them. If a Jew gives an additional fee to the keeper of the cave, an iron door which dates from the time of our forefathers opens, and the visitor descends with a lighted candle. He crosses two empty caves, and in the third sees six tombs, on which the names of the three Patriarchs and their wives are inscribed inHebrew characters. The cave is filled with barrels containing bones of people, which are taken there as to a sacred place. At the end of the field of the Machpelah stands Abraham's house with a spring in front of it" ("Itinerary," ed. Asher, pp. 40-42, Hebr.). Samuel b. Samson visited the cave in 1210; he says that the visitor must descend by twenty-four steps in a passageway so narrow that the rock touches him on either hand ("Pal. Explor. Fund," Quarterly Statement, 1882, p. 212). Now the cave is concealed by a mosque; this was formerly a church, built by the Crusaders between 1167 and 1187 and restored by the Arabs (comp. Stanley, "Sinai and Palestine," p. 149).
>
> **Tomb of Adam and Eve.**
>
> **In Rabbinical Literature:**
>
> The name of "Machpelah" (= "the doubled one") belongs, according to the Rabbis, to the cave alone, their reasons for the name being various: it was a double cave, with two stories (Rab); it contained pairs of tombs (Samuel); it had a double value in the eyes of people who saw it; any one buried there could expect a double reward in the future world; when God buried Adam there He had to fold him together (Abahu; 'Er. 53a; Gen. R. lviii. 10). Adam and Eve were the first pair buried there, and therefore Hebron, where the cave was situated, bore the additional name of "Kirjath-arba" (= "the city of four"; i.e., of the tombs of Adam and Eve, Abraham and Sarah, Isaac and Rebekah, Jacob and Leah ('Er. 53a; Soṭah 13a; comp. Gen. R. lviii. 4).
>
> According to Pirḳe R. El. xxxvi., the cave of Machpelah was at Jebus, and the reason that induced Abraham to buy it was the following: When Abraham went to fetch the calf for his guests (comp. Gen. xviii. 7) it escaped to the cave of Machpelah. Abraham ran after it, and when he entered the cave he saw Adam and Eve lying in their beds as though they were sleeping, while lighted candles were around them, exhaling a fragrant odor. Abraham, filled with a desire to possess the cave, determined to buy it at any price. The Jebusites, however, refused to sell it to him until he had sworn that when his descendants conquered the land of Canaan they would spare the city of Jebus (Jerusalem). Abraham accordingly took the oath, and the Jebusites inscribed it on brazen idols which they placed in the markets of the city. This was the reason why the children of Benjamin did not drive out the inhabitants of Jebus (Judges i. 21). Abraham secured his purchase of the cave of Machpelah by a formal deed signed by four witnesses: Amigal, son of Abishua the Hittite; Elihoreph, son of Ashunah the Hivite; 'Iddon, son of Ahira the Gardite; Aḳdul, son of 'Abudish the Zidonite ("Sefer ha-Yashar," section "Ḥayye Sarah," p. 37a, Leghorn, 1870).

There is a Christian tradition that Adam was buried in Jerusalem on the very spot that Jesus was crucified.

> It is most likely not true that Jesus was crucified on top of the tomb of Adam. The idea that Golgotha had a twin significance—as the site of Jesus’ death and as Adam’s burial place—stems from an ancient legend fueled by medieval allegory and various theological considerations.
>
> The notion that Jesus was crucified on top of the tomb of Adam crops up fairly early in Christian history. Origen, Chrysostom, and Jerome all make reference to the idea—although, notably, none of those three ever conceded the truth of the tale. Epiphanius of Salamis (c. 315—403) wrote that “our Lord Jesus Christ was crucified on Golgotha, nowhere else than where Adam’s body lay buried. For after leaving Paradise, living opposite it for a long time and growing old, Adam later came and died in this place, I mean Jerusalem, and was buried there, on the site of Golgotha. This was probably the way the place, which means ‘Place of a Skull,’ got its name, since the contour of the site bears no resemblance to a skull” (Panarion, Book I, §45, “Against Severians”).
>
> Jewish tradition says that Adam was buried in Hebron, in the Cave of Machpelah, the same place where Abraham and his family were later buried (see Genesis 49:30–31). There are a couple of different Islamic legends that also deal with Adam’s final resting place. According to one tradition related by Ibn Kathir, Noah took Adam’s remains on board the ark with him and later reburied Adam in Jerusalem.
>
> A Christian tradition—the one mentioned by Origen, et al.—places the tomb of Adam in Jerusalem immediately beneath the place where Jesus’ cross stood. In some versions of the story, Adam’s burial site is called the Cave of Treasures. Today in Jerusalem, along the Via Dolorosa, there is a small room near the Stone of Unction before Station 14 called the Chapel of Adam, where Adam was supposedly buried. To the east of the chapel, through a window, what is known as the Golgotha Rock is visible. The rock is cracked (a feature attributed to the earthquake mentioned in Matthew 27:51). According to the story, the crack allowed Jesus’ blood to drip down into Adam’s grave, onto Adam’s skull—and in this way redeeming the first man. - [Is it true that Jesus was crucified above the tomb of Adam?](https://www.gotquestions.org/tomb-of-Adam.html)

True that this is just a tradition to some or a legend to others, some Catholic mystics lean towards it being true. Blessed Catherine Emmerich writes of this in her revelations which one is free to believe or not.

The following is taken from the revelations of Blessed Catherine Emmerich’s book ***The Dolorous Passion of Our Lord Jesus Christ*** by Anne Catherine Emmerich

> [**On the Name of Calvary.**](http://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/03d/1774-1824,_Emmerich._Anne_Catherine,_Dolorous_Passion_Of_Our_Lord_Jesus_Christ,_EN.pdf)
>
> Whilst meditating on the name of Golgotha, Calvary, the place of skulls, borne by the rock upon which Jesus was crucified, I became deeply absorbed in contemplation, and beheld in spirit all ages from the time of Adam to that of Christ, and in this vision the origin of the name was made known to me. I here give all that I remember on this subject.
>   I saw Adam, after his expulsion from Paradise, weeping in the grotto where Jesus sweated blood and water, on Mount Olivet. I saw how Seth was promised to Eve in the grotto of the manger at Bethlehem, and how she brought him forth in that same grotto. I also saw Eve living in some caverns near Hebron, where the Essenian Monastery of Maspha was afterwards established.
>
> I then beheld the country where Jerusalem was built, as it appeared after the Deluge, and the land was all unsettled, black, stony, and very different from what it had been before. At an immense depth below the rock which constitutes Mount Calvary (which was formed in this spot by the rolling, of the waters), I saw the tomb of Adam and Eve. The head and one rib were wanting to one of the skeletons, and the remaining head was placed within the same skeleton, to which it did not belong. The bones of Adam and Eve had not all been left in this grave, for Noah had some of them with him in the ark, and they were transmitted from generation to generation by the Patriarchs. Noah, and also Abraham, were in the habit, when offering sacrifice, of always laying some of Adam’s bones upon the altar, to remind the Almighty of his promise. When Jacob gave Joseph his variegated robe, he at the same time gave him some bones of Adam, to be kept as relies. Joseph always wore them on his bosom, and they were placed with his own bones in the first reliquary which the children of Israel brought out of Egypt I have seen many similar things, bat some I have for. gotten, and the others time fails me to describe.
>
> As regards the origin of the name of Calvary, I here give all I know. I beheld the mountain which bears this name as it was in the time of the Prophet Eliseus. It was not the same then as at the time of our Lords Crucifixion, but was a hill, with many walls and caverns, resembling tombs, upon it. I saw the Prophet Eliseus descend into these caverns, I cannot say whether in reality or only in a vision, and I saw him take out a skull from a stone sepulchre in which bones were resting. Some one who was by his side—I think an angel—said to him, ‘This is the skull of Adam.’ The prophet was desirous to take it away, but his companion forbade him. I saw upon the skull some few hairs of a fair colour.
>
> I learned also that the prophet having related what had happened to him, the spot received the name of Calvary. Finally, I saw that the Cross of Jesus was placed vertically over the skull of Adam. I was informed that this spot was the exact centre of the earth; and at the same time I was shown the numbers and measures proper to every country, but I have forgotten them, individually as well as in general. Yet I have seen this centre from above, and as it were from a bird’s-eye view. In that way a person sees far more clearly than on a map all the different countries, mountains, deserts, seas, rivers, towns, and even the smallest places, whether distant or near at hand.

The Orthodox Church also believes in this tradition!

[image]

[Chapel of Adam, Church of the Holy Sepulchre](https://churchoftheholysepulchre.net/pictures/)

For more information about this subject matter one can glean through the following articles:

- [Chapel of Adam, the Church of the Holy Sepulchre - Jerusalem](https://www.360cities.net/image/chapel-of-adam-the-church-of-the-holy-sepulchre-jerusalem)
- [Church of the Holy Sepulchre](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_the_Holy_Sepulchre)

Answer (score -3):

The moment they ate the forbidden fruit of forbidiness.

> But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat,
>   for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die (Genesis 2:17).

Comment: Somehow I doubt Adam could live for 930 years. I mean 120 years seems reasonable but 930? The earth must have been moving pretty damn fast around the sun back in the day. Then again 930 birthday cakes seems pretty good going.

Comment: @RobKwasowski  Satan said they would not die

Comment: @Jiafjooafj1231 I think OP is asking about physical death rather than the notion of spiritual death via separation from God by disobedience.  Also, there are a great many long lived folks recorded in the early parts of Genesis; why doubt Adam's recorded age?